# Web Page and its Downloaded Source Code are Different . Strange but True.!

Tags: twitter, web

I was going through Twitter Web Pages for my project. Found this problem.
E.g.
Web Page:https://twitter.com/SrBachchan
Page Source(when viewed in the browser by Right Clicking) :
view-source:https://twitter.com/SrBachchan

Downloaded the source code by curl command. The downloaded source code(through curl) is different from the original source code.

I tried downloading the source code using python also(used urllib2.urlopen). Its the same as obtained by curl.

Can anyone throw some light on this.?

Comment: Page can act differently based on different user-agents.

Comment: So, what is the procedure for getting the exact source code ?

Comment: use twitter apis [Twitter APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1). Through apis you can download every thing of user

Comment: i am relatively new to twitter. Could you please elaborate by mentioning the name of twitter api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
One needs to add the header '--header "Accept-Language: en" ' for getting the exact source code of the language.

E.g. curl  --header "Accept-Language: en" https://twitter.com/SrBachchan   would do the job.